# How to calculate the modulo using the remainder?

Tags: arithmetic

I'm writing an [arbitrary-precision arithmetic library](https://github.com/brick/math).

I have methods to calculate the quotient and remainder of a division.

I'd now like to add the modulo operator. [Modulo and remainder are not the same](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13683563/759866) for negative numbers.

**How can I calculate the modulo of 2 numbers, using a `remainder()` function** and other basic arithmetic operations?

Comment: Modulo is not a function that returns a number. But if it were it would be the remainder function..  If the remainder function is programmed to return negative numbers then just add $n$ to the result if the result is negative.  But you should kind in mind that in *mathematics* modulo is *not* a function that returns an integer.  It's one of a a finite number of equivalence classees into which integers may fall.

Comment: Modulo $2$ means even or odd.  The remainder function *might* be *programmed* to sometime return $-1$.  If so, just replace that with $1$.

Comment: Sorry, this may not be the right website to ask then. I don't have a background in mathematics, but in computer science, modulo *is* a function that takes 2 integers and returns an integer. See for example: [123 mod -20](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=123+mod+-20).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As found on https://www.lemoda.net/c/modulo-operator/ :

`%` being the remainder operator, the modulo can be calculated as:

```
((a % b) + b) % b
```

I successfully verified that the result is correct for all sign combinations of the dividend and the divisor.

Comment: You could also do an *if* clause.  If $r =a\% b< 0$ then $a \mod b = r + b$.  Otherwise $a\mod b = r$.

Comment: This breaks my unit tests. A failing example: `1 mod -123` [should return](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1+mod+-123) `-122`, but returns `1` using your algorithm.

Comment: Oh... you are can have negative modulus?  Um why should $1 \mod {-123} = -123$ instead $1$.  What is your *definition* of modulus?  And what is your definition of "remainder"?  And what do you *want* the answer to be.  This really seems like just bean pushing to me.

Comment: You overlooked this part:  "Integers congruent to -122 mod -123:

-245, -368, -491, -614, -737, -860, -983, -1106, -1229, -1352, ...

".  Like I said.  Modulus is *not* an operation that returns *one* value.  To me mind $1\mod -123=1$ is a more desirable answer than $-122$ but they are both valid.  It really depends on what you *want* the definition to be.  To my mind $1 \mod x$ should *ALWAYS* be $1$ no matter what $x$ is.

Comment: TBH I don't know, I'm just following the convention used by the Google calculator and Wolfram Alpha. [This article](https://rob.conery.io/2018/08/21/mod-and-remainder-are-not-the-same/) explains, I think, which kind of `mod` is expected in computer systems.